# Dynamic font size to draw string inside a rectangle

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I am drawing a rectangle in the paint method of a control. There is a zoom factor to consider, e.g. each positive `MouseWheel` event causes the control to repaint and then the rectangle gets bigger. Now I am drawing a string inside this rectangle, but I couldn't figure out how to relate the font size of the text to the growth or shrinkage of the rectangle that the text is supposed to be inside it.

Here is some relevant part of my code:

```
public GateShape(Gate gate, int x, int y, int zoomFactor, PaintEventArgs p)
{
    _gate = gate;
    P = p;
    StartPoint = new Point(x, y);
    ShapeSize = new Size(20 + zoomFactor * 10, 20 + zoomFactor * 10);
    Draw();
}

public Bitmap Draw()
{

    #if DEBUG
    Debug.WriteLine("Drawing gate '" + _gate.GetGateType() + "' with symbol '" + _gate.GetSymbol() + "'");
    #endif

    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
    DrawingRect = new Rectangle(StartPoint.X, StartPoint.Y, ShapeSize.Width, ShapeSize.Height);
    P.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, DrawingRect);

    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat
    {
        Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
        LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    };
    using(Font font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 8)) //what to do here?
    P.Graphics.DrawString(_gate.GetSymbol(), font, Brushes.Black, DrawingRect, sf);

    return null;
}
```

A hardcoded simple multiplication by the zoom factor seems to some how work but this is not the smartest way I assume. `int size = 8 + _zoomFactor * 6;`

Comment: The best solution I ever found for this problem is repeated calls to `MeasureString`, adjusting font size until you're just under the max size that fits.

Comment: Or, you could have the mousewheel affect the font size, and draw the rectangle around the text instead of vice versa.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thanks a lot for the tip. I am sure it will work. But I wonder if HansPassant has a solution :D

Comment: Maybe you can render the text on a bitmap and draw the bitmap scaled.

Comment: Or, just use the [Graphics.ScaleTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx.aspx) method for your zoom factor, and leave the rest to the framework.

Comment: @IronGeek OMG ScaleTransform does magic! I wish I knew about it before....could saved months! I like to mark it as answer so please write it as answer.

Comment: @SaeidYazdani I've posted my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [`Graphics.ScaleTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx.aspx) method to apply your zoom factor.

Example:

```
public GateShape(Gate gate, int x, int y, float zoomFactor, PaintEventArgs p)
{
  _gate = gate;
  P = p;
  StartPoint = new Point(x, y);
  ShapeSize = new Size(20, 20);
  ZoomFactor = zoomFactor;
  Draw();
}

public Bitmap Draw()
{
  P.Graphics.ScaleTransform(ZoomFactor, ZoomFactor);
  ...
  // The rest of rendering logic should be the same (as is previously written)
}
```